# Crystal report render all previous pages

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

i am using crystal report viewer for ASP.net version 13.0.2000.0

i have report with many group items

when i press in any group item from the left navigation panel of crystal report

it take too much time to load the report page

i have investigate on this problem and found that i have some image export using third party map provider during the render process

but i want to know how to prevent crystal report from load all previous groups item when i select one from bottom

for example if i have group items

Bill no1

bill no2

bill no3

bill no4

bill no5

when i click on bill no3 the crystal report take too much time due to rendering all items before bill no3

and when i return back to bill no1 or any items previous no3 it take no time to display it due to it rendered before

how to prevent this action

i need to inform cr to render the pressed item only to take suitable time

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you Smita for your response but i have tried to remove the next and previous button but not help i cannot disable the category tree because it must be displayed as a customer need 
all i need is to prevent cr from loading all previous pages when i click page in middle of category tree